# Using a mutex in a Windows 10 device driver resulting in code 39

Tags: windows, installation, driver, device, code39

I'm developing a Windows 10 device driver for a virtual camera based off the avstream/avscamera example in the windows driver samples repository.
The driver will gets its frames from a separately run Windows app via shared memory synchronized by a Mutex.

I can build the driver without errors, but when I try to install it with Hdwwiz.exe, I get the following error:

> Windows cannot load the device driver for this hardware.
>     The driver may be corrupted or missing (Code 39).

Any ideas/suggestions?

If I comment out all the Mutex and Shared memory methods, there are no problems in installing the driver. If I uncomment just the line that does the CreateMutexA call so it reads as:

> void myinitfunction() {
>    mutex = CreateMutexA(&securityAttributes, false, "mymutexname");
>   }

I again get the Code 39 error.

This suggests that I'm linking the runtime incorrectly.

Possibly relevant info:
I'm trying to install the 64 bit version of the driver on a laptop that has a 64 bit build version of 
 17134.rs4_release.180410-1804
I've got the Windows SDK Version set to 10.0.17763.0. (the build failed when the SDK version was set to 17134 because the Windows Kits/10/bin/10.0.17134.0 directory didn't contain an instance of stampinf.exe file).

My library directories are:

> C:\Program Files %28x86%29\Windows Kits\10\Lib\10.0.17763.0\um\x64;
>   C:\Program Files %28x86%29\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\lib\x64\store;
>   $(LibraryPath)

The Windows/inf/setupapi.dev.log file doesn't tell me much more. It has the text:

> Device Status: 0x01802001, Problem: 0x0 (0x00000000)
>        dvi:                {Restarting Devices} 11:09:38.030
>        dvi:                     Start: ROOT\AVSCAMERA\0000 !!!  dvi:                     Device not started: Device has problem: 0x27
>   (CM_PROB_DRIVER_FAILED_LOAD), problem status: 0xc0000034.
>        dvi:                {Restarting Devices exit} 11:09:38.064
>        dvi:           {Configure Device - exit(0x00000000)} 11:09:38.065
>        dvi:           Device Status: 0x01802401, Problem: 0x27  Device Status: 0x01802001, Problem: 0x0 (0x00000000)
>        dvi:                {Restarting Devices} 11:09:38.030
>        dvi:                     Start: ROOT\AVSCAMERA\0000 !!!  dvi:                     Device not started: Device has problem: 0x27
>   (CM_PROB_DRIVER_FAILED_LOAD), problem status: 0xc0000034.
>        dvi:                {Restarting Devices exit} 11:09:38.064
>        dvi:           {Configure Device - exit(0x00000000)} 11:09:38.065
>        dvi:           Device Status: 0x01802401, Problem: 0x27

Comment: `CreateMutexA` is exported by `Kernel32.dll` you can not use it in kernel. in kernel exist another synchronization objects. for example [*Fast Mutexes and Guarded Mutexes*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/kernel/fast-mutexes-and-guarded-mutexes), push locks, etc..

Comment: Whats the rule for determining what can and can't be used in the kernel? Is there a document some place?

Comment: you can use in kernel what is exported by *ntoskrnl.exe*, *hal.dll*, *fltmgr.sys*, etc. import only from kernel mode drivers and dll. you can not use user mode dlls